# Regular expression to check for non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression for .NET program to ensure the string does not contain any letters or numbers. underscore and other special characters are ok.
An example of a string would be ".____"

I need to check the string and ensure that it does not have any numbers or letters. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`^[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+$`

\p{L} matches a character from the Unicode category “letter”
\p{Nd} matches a character from the Unicode category “decimal digit”

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex which allows the strings which won't contain letters or digits.

```
^[^\dA-Za-z]*$
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a string. `[^..]` negated character class. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times. Change `*` in the above regex to `+`, if you don't want to match blank lines.

```
^[^\dA-Za-z]+$
```

OR

```
^(?!.*[\dA-Za-z]).*$
```

`(?!.*[\dA-Za-z])` Negative lookahead which asserts that the string won't contain a letter or digit. It matches only those lines where the condition is true.

OR

```
^[^\p{L}\p{N}]*$
```

`\p{L}` matches any kind of letters from any language and `\p{N}` matches any kind of digits. By putting this into a negated  character class like `[^\p{L}\p{N}]*` would match any character but not of letters or digits zero or more times.

Comment: could you please break it down for me? I am trying to get familiar with regex expressions.  Also I tried entering the first expression into a tester and I got an error "trailing whitespace"

Comment: change `*` to `+` like `^[^\dA-Za-z]+$`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to raise an error if an alphanumeric character is found, it might be simpler to do the following:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

You don't need begin and end anchors in this case as the regex will simply look for an alphanumeric character, and return true upon finding the first one.